# Symfony 2 -> 3 upgrade issue: Must be instance of ControllerResolver TraceableControllerResolver given

Tags: symfony

After upgrading to Symfony 3 the following event listener now receives  TraceableControllerResolver instead of ControllerResolver. This is causing the following type hint errors:

```
must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolverInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver given
```

This only seems to be the case in development, in production the type remains ControllerResolver.

I can remove the type hinting but it feels like this is not the best solution. Is this the only solution or is there a better design pattern in symfony 3 for what I'm trying to achieve - which is ultimately get the currently matched controller within an event listener.

Here is some example code to illustrate the issue:

The config:

```
    listener:
        class: \EventListener\AccessCheckListener
        scope: request
        arguments: ["@controller_resolver","@session", "@router", "@request_stack"]
        tags:
           - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onAccessDeniedException }
```

The listener:

```
class AccessCheckListener
{
    protected $_session;
    protected $_router;
    protected $_request_stack;
    protected $controllerResolver;

    public function __construct(ControllerResolver $controllerResolver, Session $session, Router $router, RequestStack $_request_stack)
    {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_router = $router;
        $this->_request_stack = $_request_stack;
        $this->controllerResolver = $controllerResolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message:

> must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolverInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver given

there is no `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolverInterface` interface in 3.4 Symfony version.

Change `ControllerResolverInterface`'s use namespace to  `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller` in the event listener.

Comment: Ok cool thanks. The error message was from a previous attempt at a solution which was to change the type hint from ControllerResolver to ControllerResolverInterface, to get around the issue that the type changes from ControllerResolver to TraceableControllerResolver between dev and production.

So the complete solution for those coming across the issue when migration to v3 is to change the type hint to ControllerResolverInterface and add the correct use statement to use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolverInterface